# Pandas datatime conversion using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have my time stored in the format `YYYYMMDDhhmm` in my dataframe, eg. `200902110403`.

Pandas can automatically convert this into a `datetime` object and I'm doing that like this:

```
temp_date=(pd.to_datetime(indexed_data.index.str[0:12], infer_datetime_format=True)).to_pydatetime()
```

(I don't fully understand the difference between a `datetime` object and a `datetimeindex` but I don't think that's the source of my problems)

I then use the `data2num` function from the `netcdf4` library to convert this to days since my reference time like this,

```
days=date2num(temp_date, 'days since 2009-01-01')
```

This works and returns the days as I want

```
array([ 212.03333333,  212.03333333,  212.03472222, ...,  242.95416667,
    242.95416667,  242.99583333])
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to all work in one go and I don't understand why.

Why doesn't this work?

```
indexed_data['date']=(pd.to_datetime(indexed_data.index.str[0:12], infer_datetime_format=True)).to_pydatetime()
indexed_data['days']=date2num(indexed_data['date'], 'days since 2009-01-01')
```

> TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('

but this does:

```
temp_date=(pd.to_datetime(indexed_data.index.str[0:12],infer_datetime_format=True)).to_pydatetime()
indexed_data['date']=temp_date
indexed_data['fdays']=date2num(temp_date, 'days since 2009-01-01')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `netcdf4`, but you should be able to accomplish what you want without it:

```
date_strs = ['200902110403', '200902120403', '200902130403', '200902140403', '200902150403']
df = pd.DataFrame(date_strs, columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Date']

0   2009-02-11 04:03:00
1   2009-02-12 04:03:00
2   2009-02-13 04:03:00
3   2009-02-14 04:03:00
4   2009-02-15 04:03:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To get the time elapsed since your reference date, you can subtract two `datetime` objects which returns a `timedelta` object:

```
(df['Date'] - pd.to_datetime('2009-01-01'))

0   41 days 04:03:00
1   42 days 04:03:00
2   43 days 04:03:00
3   44 days 04:03:00
4   45 days 04:03:00
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And if you just want the number of days as an integer, you call the `.dt.days` accessor on the above series:

```
df['Days'] = (df['Date'] - pd.to_datetime('2009-01-01')).dt.days
df['Days']

0    41
1    42
2    43
3    44
4    45
Name: Days, dtype: int64
```

A `datetimeindex` object is simply a `datetime` object that is set as the index of your dataframe.